# Fragment Transactions with scrollview

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

You have an Activity A --> display a fragment B (scrollView), on next button you have fragment C replaced with relative Layout. But the view is not replaced.

Comment: so what is you question?

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView Defines as follows :
"A view group that allows the view hierarchy placed within it to be scrolled. Scroll view may have only one direct child placed within it. To add multiple views within the scroll view, make the direct child you add a view group, for example LinearLayout, and place additional views within that LinearLayout."

-**ScrollView is not a base view hence wrapping the scrolling in base views like (Linear Layout,RelativeLayout Can solve your problem**